# How to use the "display" property for the scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I was creating a website without the scroll bar anywhere in the site and by using the code,

`::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none; }`.

And I need to display the scroll bar for particular div. But, the scroll bar is not visible.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Ypj/41/) is the sample of my code. All I want is, scroll bar to be visible in the inner box and not elsewhere.

Thanks in advance, Guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with

```
*:not(.box)::-webkit-scrollbar{
     display: none;
}
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/v2Ypj/44/.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Ypj/45/)

```
*{margin:0 auto;padding:0px; }
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%;}

.big-box{
     height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

.box{
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: @DOC ASAREL have found a solution I was looking for http://jsfiddle.net/v2Ypj/44/.

Thanks for your Effort, himanshu.